# separate data of single worksheet to two worksheets in excel (VBA or other solutions)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set with 1000 entries of the following form:

ID        Name                        Value

---

1        Name1                         55
  2        Name1                         5
  3        Name2                         6
  4        Name1                         44
  5        Name2                         33
  6        Name1                         22

This data is all contained in a single worksheet. I wish excel to separate the data according to name then place each row in a separate worksheet in the same workbook. for above data excel must create two sheets (Name1 & Name2).

I try macro record, but I can't fix generated macro. It work for current data, but after adding new data, the macro don't work well.

Is this possible with VBA or other solution?

Comment: Show us what you have tried? You know, if you want "out of the box solutions" pay a developer...

Comment: I try macro record, then I can't fix the generated macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code should do what you are looking for:

```
Sub Macro2()

Range("B2").Select
Do Until Selection.Value = "xxx"
    If Selection.Value = "Name1" Then
        ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Else
        ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet3").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select

Loop
End Sub
```

Assumption:

1- the main data is inside sheet1

2- there are sheet2 and sheet3 available to copy the data to

3- after the last row of data add a row that has xxx for each cell otherwise it is an infinite loop

4- The Name1 and Name2 are in column B